# android : how check that location manager has getLastKnownLocation?

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

i have some code :

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

activity fields

```
 private LocationManager locationManager;
 private LocationListener mlocListener;
```

onCreate initialization

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

class MyLocationListener

```
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
        }


        @Override

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
        }

    }
```

and i have button, onclick = getting users gps location

```
public void getUserLocation(View v){
    boolean enabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!enabled) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
              startActivity(intent);
    } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()) + " " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

on getLastKnownLocation i have error. how can i check that locationManager has getLastKnownLocation ?? requestLocationUpdates automatic has to get location, hasnt it ??

And im interesting, which parametrs in requestLocationUpdates (minTime and minDistance) should better to use ?? i dont want eat users battery too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i check that locationManager has getLastKnownLocation ??

Just a null check will do the required

> requestLocationUpdates automatic has to get location, hasnt it ??

As soon you request either from network or from Gps. It start looking for location updates.
but it can take times.

Gps updates are more slower to come. Need open sky but are more accurate.

network update are more faster to come. but are less accurate as compare to GPS.
Incase of wifi network accuracy comes around 50-100 which is good for most of the scnario.

> And im interesting, which parametrs in requestLocationUpdates (minTime and minDistance) 
>   should better to use ?? i dont want eat users battery too much

use 0,0 
as soon you get a update of desired accuracy unregister from listening location updates.

Comment: i have error here Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); i cannt null check after

Comment: i have exeption java.lang.NullPointerException but why i didnt get null from  getLastKnownLocation and failed on it, not after?? and why i did requestLocationUpdates  but location manager hasnt this LastKnownLocation ??

Comment: null exeption solved, tell me please, why requestLocationUpdates dont set tLastKnownLocation?? and gettLastKnownLocation allways return null?? i test application on emulator, and while dont set location by console, it allways returns null.. and on my device (phone) it always returns null, but gps is enabled

Comment: I wonder are you correctly using the GPS and Network Updates. 
Anyways you can save the last update by yourself too. Save the Location object in onLocationChanged delegate to use it. save it on some instance Location variable. if you onLocationChanged delegates is not getting called even for once. that means you are not getting any location updates. if it is getting called then you got it. and getLastKnownLocation should also work to return that . But i itself don't rely much on that. i save location update of desired accuracy and unregister from listening location update.

Comment: also try to do this all on real device

Comment: i have a problem, that in my device onLocationChanged never calls.. gps is enabled and listner is setted to location manager ("onCreate initialization" code) what could be the problem??

Comment: solved, thanks, i just have to go outside from home, gps doesnt find satellite.. i have to go for a walk from the house more often, lol )

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this..
   /*
     * getting the best location using the location manager
     */
    mLocation = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    mBestProvider = mLocation.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = mLocation.getLastKnownLocation(mBestProvider);
    mLocation.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            Constants.MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
            Constants.MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new LocationListenerManager()
    );
    if(location!=null) {
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude(); 
           }
            else { // handle by urself

            }
```